# Textfield values set to empty when coming back from previous view controller

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, navigation, uitextfield

Visit this [image]: https://media.giphy.com/media/13jWe2R65tiDrW/giphy.gif

[Storyboard using segues Storyboard Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OL7BI.png)

**ViewController File**

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

```
@IBOutlet var trainNumberTextField : UITextField!
@IBOutlet var train2 : UITextField!

var stringVal : String!
var stringVal2 : String!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    trainNumberTextField.delegate = self
    train2.delegate = self
    trainNumberTextField.tag = 1
    trainNumberTextField.text = stringVal
    train2.text = stringVal2
    train2.tag = 2


}

func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    if textField.tag == 1 {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "text2table", sender: self)
    }
    if textField.tag == 2 {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "text2table2", sender: self)
    }

    return false
}
```

}

**Second View Controller :**

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

```
    let indexpath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow

    let currentcell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexpath!)!

    print(currentcell.textLabel!.text!)

    textOneValue = currentcell.textLabel!.text!
    let index = textOneValue.index(textOneValue.startIndex, offsetBy: 5)
     finalString =  textOneValue.substring(to: index)


    performSegue(withIdentifier: "table2text", sender: self)

}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "table2text"{

    // =========== Destination view contorller name ===========
    let   viewcontorller = segue.destination as! ViewController

    viewcontorller.stringVal = finalString


    }
```

> Entering one textfield value automatically clearing perviously entered textfield value

Comment: I would suggest to ask a clear question, by describing what's the issue that are you facing. Adding images should be for clarity, not for asking the whole question. Also, you should add a code snippet for a specific code, me as a viewer don't have to download the whole project to get it...

Comment: I'm new to stackvoerflow. Thanks for the suggestion. Please watch this image link : https://media.giphy.com/media/13jWe2R65tiDrW/giphy.gif. Textfield values are missing.

Comment: I'm using storyboards with segues with identifiers to move from one vc to another vc. In my app I need to enter to and fro train names. When user taps on firstTextField a tableview will appear and user taps on selected cell and selected cell value placed as firstTextfieldValue and same for secondTextField. Problem is, when entering second first value is lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- When you push back to the origin viewController, It's better to replace using "push" Segue by "popViewController" method .
- It's also good using data consistent strategy.
- And the reason:
  You should consider the viewController's lifecycle.
  When you push back to the origin viewController, using "push" Segue makes the  origin viewController's "viewDidLoad" method is called again. 
  Then the unchosen textfield's value(stringVal2) is reset to nil.
  So not saved.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'm new to iOS, please tell how to popViewContorller..? I'm not using navigation controller. After table cell selection I need to show value on pervious viewcontorller textfield.

Comment: It's best if you ask a new question. That way many more people will see it and have a chance to respond.